# Cant connect to mysql server on AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS RDS. I have created RDS instance.But i dont know, how can i connect this DB.
I tried like this

```
mysql -h awsinstanamehere.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u username -p
```

*After i entered password and i am getting some error like this*

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'awsinstanamehere.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)

**Need to set any security setting in AWS console?**

**Note:**
I want to import tables for that DB

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

RDS has a security group - in the AWS console, RDS, there's an entry for security groups.

If you didn't explicitly create a security group, you are probably using "default".  You should probably have one group per RDS instance.

You will need to make sure that port 3306 is open to your local network, as well as whatever application you will be using to connect to it.  You can allow access by IP or by security group.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Now i can access database. How can i import all tables from ec2 instance to rds. or how can i import tables from local system to RDS instance .

Comment: When I try to do that I get forwarded to the VPC management console instead, is there something I can do from there?

Answer (score 3):

Same error, but in my case the problem wasn't related to security groups.
I forgot to add an additional route to the route table of the subnets.

See below the 2nd route where the internet gateway was added as the target for all non local traffic (outside the VPC):

[image]

Comment: thank you, you made my day !!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a little trouble with these answers so here are the steps I followed to get it working...

1. Logged in via ssh to my ec2 instance.
2. typed this command, `curl canhazip.com`
3. copied the ip address that was returned
4. went to my `VPC Dashboard` in aws
5. clicked on `Security Groups` in the left column
6. clicked on the checkbox next to one of the security groups
7. clicked `Edit` under the `Inbound Rules` tab
8. added this rule : `MySQL/Aurora (3306) TCP (6) 3306 [IP from #2]/32`
9. saved

I did this for every security group until the mysql connection worked from the command line, then deleted all of the ones that I didn't need, and retested to make sure I could still connect.

Answer (score -1):

By default security group defined by AWS is not configured for publicly available inbound source. You will have to modify the security group inbound source ip to 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: This is not a good answer as that opens it up to everyone. Should put your IP explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me when I added the port 3306, while it was only the 1433 it was not working....

so the security group was created like this

security group vpc-XXXXXX

**MY SQL / TCP / 1433 / 0.0.0.0/0** 
**MY SQL / TCP / 1433 / ::/0** 
**MTSQL/Aurora / TCP / 3306 / 0.0.0.0/0**   
**MSSQL/Autora / TCP / 3306 / ::/0**

following the headers TYPE / Protocol / Port Range / Source