# AWS RDS php connection

Tags: php, mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I can't connect to MySQL RDS instance on AWS through php. It gave me this error:

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\RESULTS\conne\New Text Document.php on line 7
>   Connection failed: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Could you please help me to get through. I am new to AWS and stuff. So I would be much thankful if you could describe this issue in detail.

Comment: Did you add your IP to the security group of the RDS database?

Comment: Could you please tell us more about your situation? For example, is the PHP app running on an Amazon EC2 instance? Is it in the same VPC as the Amazon RDS instance? What is the configuration of the Security Group associated with the RDS instance? How is the app referencing the database (eg via DNS Name, and does it resolve successfully)? Feel free to edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: @GreyHands Noo. I need to access that database publicly . How could I do that . Please guide me If you could.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you do not have the ip address of the server hosting your php application whitelisted under your rds security group? Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21498471/6763406