# Unable to connect to AWS RDS using AWS CLI - Error 2002

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I've set up a basic AWS RDS in the free tier. No public access but created a security group with my IP address added as an inbound rule.

For authentication I have RDS password plus AWS IAM.

I try to connect to the db via my computer (Ubuntu) with the following command:

```
mysql -h <db-conn>.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u admin -p
```

I've already looked at this answer - [Cant connect to mysql server on AWS RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495448/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-aws-rds) My port isn't blocked and I've checked the security group. I am able to successfully run AWS CLI commands like this:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --filters "Name=engine,Values=mysql" --query "*[].[DBInstanceIdentifier,Endpoint.Address,Endpoint.Port,MasterUsername]"
```

But every time I run the `mysql` command, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '<db-conn>.amazonaws.com' (115)
```

Would love some assistance with this. Thanks!

Comment: If you setted the public access to NO, you won't be able to access from your computer, just from the AWS VPC. You need to set it as YES, and then in the security group, block all access except for your public IP

Comment: @nacho doesn't the security group add my IP to the same VPC?

Comment: No, it adds your IP to the firewall rules, but if you said the RDS does not have public access, that includes all IP outside the VPC, and that rule is over the firewall rules

Comment: @nacho good to know. So how do I make it public but restrict it to my IP only?

Comment: Modify the Publicly Accesible property to YES in your RDS DB instance config, modifying it in Connectivity, Additional configuration

Comment: @nacho once I make it publicly accessible, do I need to change anything in the security group to restrict everything else but my IP?

Comment: You should allow only your public IP and the VPC you are using

Comment: If your database was launched in a **private subnet**, then it will not be reachable from the Internet. If it was launched in a **public subnet**, then the above instructions will work.

Comment: @nacho thanks... I was able to access after making it public and i tested from a different IP and I couldn't access it so it seems to be working now. Would you like to make an answer so I can accept it and give you the credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For being able to connect to your AWS RDS system and not letting anyone to connect you need to do the following steps:

- Set your Publicly Accesible property to YES in your RDS configuration. That will give the system a Public Subnet address and allow it to be accesible from outside your VPC.
- Go to your security group and allow access to your RDS system (the port 3306 that you are trying to connect) only from your VPC and from your public IP. This makes changes in your firewall rules.

In that way you will be able to access your RDS from your public IP, but noone else will be able to access.

Answer (score 0):

check your ip that config in the security group, it is need your public ip not like '192.168.xxx.xxx', you can get your public ip by google

Comment: AWS has a nice feature to select "My IP" which automatically adds your public IP. So yes, it is very much so the public one.